# is this a good way to template my site

Tags: html, jsp, twitter-bootstrap, vraptor

im planning to do something using bootstrap, where i will split the .jsp in 2 divs, the top one is the menubar.jsp and the other is the contentclicked eg:

start.jsp

```
<div id="menubar"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

when the users get access(after a login) and go to the http://www.localhost.com/restrict/start

it will run this .js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menubar").load("restrict/menubar");        
});
```

the /restrict/menubar is because i have a file called menu.jsp that have the bootstrap code of the menubar
and for each link that the client click in the menubar it will do:

```
$("#content").load("restrict/linkCliked");
```

and for each link i will have a linkCliked.jsp

it seems to work, BUT i dont know if this is a good way and secure, because if the use write the uri http://www.localhost.com/restrict/linkCliked, he will get just the linkClicked.jsp, but i want it to render the menubar.jsp too without, is there any solution that i dont have to "include" in each .jsp the menubar?

obs: using VRaptor MVC

Answer (score 0):

Your system seems OK. If you are concerned about the HTML URI being pointed to incorrectly, you can keep your templates in a separate folder than your bootstrap. If your setup is like so:

/var
/var/www
/var/www/html <- your web

You can add a new folder:

/var/www/template

And put `linkClicked.jsp` and `menubar.jsp` into that folder, calling them. A user will not be able to type in an address to get to those paths and you won't need to do any funky redirection in your server configuration either.